# Related to GP 1.3.9 - Is projection function smooth?

Tags: differential-topology

I start to think of this question when I attempt Ex 1.3.9 on *Guillemin and Pollack*'s *Differential Topology* [GP 1.3.9(b) Every manifold is locally expressible as a graph.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/435446/gp-1-3-9b-every-manifold-is-locally-expressible-as-a-graph).

I am under the impression that this is true. For the proof of the following question, I need the fact that both the projection function and its inverse are smooth. Is this true?

> Let $x_1, \dots, x_N$ be the standard coordinate functions on $\mathbb{R}^N$, and let $X$ be a $k$-dimensional submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^N$. Prove that every point $x \in X$ has a neighborhood on which the restrictions of some $k$-coordinate functions $x_{i_1}, \dots, x_{i_k}$ form a local coordinate system.

Comment: What projection do you mean?

Comment: Hi @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez thanks. this kind: $$d \varphi: T_x(X) \mapsto \text{ span}(e_{i_1}, \dots, e_{i_k})$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The projection is smooth. Note that projection is just the restriction of a linear map to the manifold. Since linear functions are smooth, this actually proves what you want (in the context of G&P).