# GP 1.3.9(b) Every manifold is locally expressible as a graph.

Tags: differential-topology

This is exercise 1.3.9(b) on *Guillemin and Pollack*'s *Differential Topology*

I believe I am pretty much done with this problem, but I still do not understand why the last step shows the existence, and what is $g$? Is it $\varphi \circ \varphi^{-1}$?

> Assume that $x_1, \dots x_k$ form a local coordinate system on a neighborhood $V$ of $x$ in $X$. Prove that there are smooth functions $g_{k+1}, \dots, g_N$ on an open set $U$ in $\mathbb{R}^k$ such that $V$ may be taken to be the set
>   $$\{(a_1, \dots, a_k, g_{k+1}(a), \dots, g_N(a))\in \mathbb{R}^N: a = (a_1, \dots, a_k) \in U\}. $$

Consider the projection $\varphi: \mathbb{R}^N \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^k$:
$$(x_1, \dots, x_N) \mapsto (x_{i_1}, \dots, x_{i_k})$$
Differentiating:
$$d \varphi: T_x(X) \mapsto \text{ span}(e_{i_1}, \dots, e_{i_k})$$

Because $\varphi$ is a diffeomorphism, so does its inverse
$$\varphi^{-1}: (a_1, \dots, a_k) \mapsto (a_1, \dots, a_k, g_{k+1}(a), \dots, g_N(a)),$$
where $a = (a_1, \dots, a_k) \in U \in \mathbb{R}^k.$

Thank you

Comment: What is $\varphi$?

Comment: Remember that Guillemin and Pollack consistently use $\phi$ as a parametrization. What does the first sentence of your problem mean?

Comment: I am really confused by that as well. I read from somewhere else that $a = (a_1, \dots, a_n)$, then $x_i(a) = a_i.$

Comment: Thanks @DanielRust, I added some information :#)

Comment: No, Wishing, it is essential that you learn definitions from your reading. Look at the bottom of p. 3 and top of p. 4. You need to explain carefully why $\varphi^{-1}$, in your notation, is of that form.